# ООП Функционал телевизора на JS -внедрить функцию

Tags: javascript, ооп

Добрый день, прошу помощи с добавление функции к существующему проекту.
Добавил функцию `_channelStatus()`, которая при выключенном телевизоре выставляет номер канала в 0, а при повторном включении возвращает канал на тот, который был выбран до этого. При самом первом включении телевизор включается на первом канале. 
Как интегрировать эту функцию, чтобы она работала согласно выше написанному описанию?

```
class TV{
  constructor() {
    this._power = false;
    this._channel = 1;
  }

  power() {
    if (this._power) {
      this._power = false;
      console.log('TV is off');
    } else {
      this._power = true;
      console.log(`TV is on. The channel is #${this._channel}`);
    }
  }

  _channelStatus() {
    if (this._power === false) {
      this._channel = 0;
    } else {
      return this._channel();
    }
  }

  selectChannel(number) {
    if (!this._power || number < 1 || number > 99 || isNaN(number) || number % parseInt(number) > 0) {
      return false
    } else {
      this._channel = number;
      console.log(`Switch to channel #${this._channel}`);
    }
  }

  info() {
    if (this._power === true) {
      console.log('TV is on');
    } else {
      console.log('TV is off');
    }
    console.log(`The channel is ${this._channel}`);
  }

}

const tv = new TV();

/*
команды телевизора
 tv.power();
 tv.selectChannel(3);
*/
```

Comment: А проблема-то в чем?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вроде нормально описал проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

где объявление функции _channel()? при чем тут ООП? если я правильно понял вас то класс нужно будет объявить таким образом:

```
class TV{
  constructor() {
    this._power = false;
    this._channel = 1;
    this._before_power_off_channel = 1;
    console.log('create obj');
  }

  power() {
    if (this._power) {
      this._power = false;
      this._before_power_off_channel = this._channel;
     console.log('_before_power_off_channel:'+this._before_power_off_channel); 
      console.log('TV is off');
    } else {
      this._power = true;
      console.log(`TV is on. The channel is #${this._channel}`);
    }
    this._channelStatus();
    console.log('TV cnannel after using power():'+this._channel);
  }

  _channelStatus() {
    if (this._power === false) {
      this._channel = 0;
    } else {
      this.selectChannel(this._before_power_off_channel);
    }
  }

  selectChannel(number) {
    if (!this._power || number < 1 || number > 99 || isNaN(number) || number % parseInt(number) > 0) {
      return false
    } else {
      this._channel = number;
      console.log(`Switch to channel #${this._channel}`);
    }
  }

  info() {
    if (this._power === true) {
      console.log('TV is on');
    } else {
      console.log('TV is off');
    }
    console.log(`The channel is ${this._channel}`);
  }

}

const tv = new TV();

/*
команды телевизора
 tv.power();
 tv.selectChannel(3);
*/
```

Comment: 1. Пользователь включил ТВ. 2. Пользователь переключил канал (например 44) 3. Пользователь выключил ТВ (канал должен переключится на 0). 4. Пользователь включил ТВ (канал должен вернуться на тот, на котором был телевизор, в данном случае это 44). Вот примерно так должно работать

Comment: после добавления [code]console.log('TV cnannel after using power():'+this._channel);[code], что в консоли после выполнения tv.power();?

Comment: вы похоже не поняли идею. При выключении канал на 0, при включении на тот, на котором был до выключения

Comment: TV cnannel after using power():1

Comment: может у вас после выключения удаляется объект tv?

Comment: нет, он не может удалится

Comment: Добавил еще логов вызов конструктора и на обновление значения кеш переменной _before_power_off_channel, смотрите логи

Answer (score 0):

В `_channelStatus` при `this._power === false` не изменяйте `this._channel`, а просто возвращайте 0. И после включения выбранный канал соханится.

Comment: будет просто 0, а при проверке через tv.info() выведет, что канал  остался тот же, что и был

Answer (score -1):

Видимо в вашем коде ошибка, и правильно так:

```
_channelStatus() {
  if (this._power === false) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return this._channel;
  }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте проверить через tv.info().

Comment: почему именно так - правильно?

Comment: Пардон, но за что минуса? Я указал на очевидные ошибки, и что они наверняка как минимум мешают, предложив исправленный вариант функции, которая, согласно своему названию, должна возвращать "состояние" канала и ни в коем случае, очевидно, не менять сам канал. А также this._channel по контексту не являлся функцией, чтобы его вызывать.

Comment: Возможно, было очень неудачно выбрано имя функции. Нельзя же называть функцию sayHello, которая занимается тем, что молча стреляет вам в ногу.